Quickly run an App Script function from within a Google Document?
How do I quickly run an App Script function from within a Google Document?

By quickly, I mean I don't want to open the Apps Script editor.
(I'm happy to define an App Script, but I want to run it from within the document window.)
By Google Document, I don't mean a Google Sheet.

What I have tried:

I don't see a way to define a Smart Chip (e.g., @myFunc) that runs a function.
I don't see a way to associate a keyboard shortcut with a App Script function.
I've looked for an App Script trigger event type that might be useful. But the only trigger event type from the document I see is "On open".


Consider setting up a time-driven trigger that runs every minute, hour, or day. The steps on how to create one are in Manage triggers manually.

@Saddles... an every-minute trigger. It's not exactly what I had in mind, but it might work in some use cases.

Apologies. What I meant by that is that those are some of the options available for time-driven triggers. You can set it up to quickly run an App Script function from within a Google Document without going to the editor and customize it to your preference.

If you would like to run it from within the document window., using onOpen(e) with a custom menu should also work.

Smart chips are a relatively new feature in Google Docs; currently, they cannot be created using Google Apps Script or even the Google Docs REST API.

Currently, you cannot associate a keyboard shortcut with an Apps Script function.

Just like what TheAddonDepot has said, since smart chips are new features in Google Docs, you may opt to file a feature request using this link. You can check the Google Apps Script release notes for any updates. Also, what Saddles recommended is also a good solution.
